# Statements ignored outside while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hello this problem has been bugging me since a week I searched everywhere in vain. I have this code
    ................

```
while ((str = buff.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] line = str.split(";");
    String part1 = line[0];
    String part2 = line[1];
    String part3 = line[2];
    String part4 = line[3];
    String part5 = line[4];

    if (c.equals(part3)) {
        st = st + part1 + ";" + part2 + ";" + part3 + ";" + part4 + ";" + part5;
        System.out.println(part1 + ";" + part2 + ";" + part3 + ";" + part4 + ";" + part5 + "\n");

        fich1_tampon.write(st);
        fich1_tampon.flush();
        fich1_tampon.newLine();

        ++i;
    }
}

System.out.println("F;" + i);
fich1_tampon.close();
buff.close();
}
```

the "System.out.println("F;" + i);" is ignored I don't know why. The code is very long but basically I'm looking for lines that have a certain String that was put in c and I'm writing those line in another file.
The result on my consoleis like this :

E;2014/02/19 20:21:06
File already exists.
N;2000;PU;Promotion iphone;232425

N;2001;PU;Promotion dell;232426

N;2002;PU;Promotion samsung;23242

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at LireFichierDecouper.decouper(LireFichierDecouper.java:70)
    at Main2.main(Main2.java:7)
Line 70 in LireFichierDecouper is "String part3 = line[2];"

PS:I'm very very new to java and eclipse, if you want me to post all the code to make it more clear I will.

Comment: It would *really* help if you could format that code more sensibly first. Get your IDE to do it if you're using one. It'll make it much, much easier to see what's going on. If you could reduce this to a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would help too. I strongly suspect that while you're doing that, you'll find the issue.

Comment: Try debugging.  The only thing that would prevent `System.out.println("F;" + i);` from being executed is an exception in an earlier line (or if you've omitted something from your sample)

Comment: The best programmers use inconsistent indentation when programming.  |=^]

Comment: Adding to @JonSkeet take a look at this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your variable name is tampon btw

Comment: You shouldn't flush a tampon. I don't know if that's your problem though.

Comment: @aetheria I starred this question just because of that joke.  Funniest thing I've read/heard all day

Comment: @aetheria I see what you did there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- If you work on *eclipse*, check "**Problems**" view for errors. Sometimes eclipse cannot compile code when your workspace has errors.
- If you work on a *running server*, may be server do not recognize your changes. Restart it, may be this helps.
- ***If double of above do not help you please explain exactly what you want and specify your development environment how it is.***

Comment: I don't have anything showing on problems but in my console I have this:

Comment: E;2014/02/19 20:21:06
File already exists.
N;2000;PU;Promotion iphone;232425

N;2001;PU;Promotion dell;232426

N;2002;PU;Promotion samsung;23242

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at LireFichierDecouper.decouper(LireFichierDecouper.java:70)
 at Main2.main(Main2.java:7)

Answer (score 0):

A debugger would be helpful to see if you are reaching that code by adding a break point at the System.out.println.  Also, where are you running the code?  System.out.println would go where directed depending on how java is run.  Please provide the command line if executing from the command line.